# Multiple one to many relationships in series

Tags: database-design

I am making DB for storing reports that have following field
`Ad_system, Ad_Campaing, Ad_Group, Keyword, Date, Impressions, Clicks, Conversions`.Logic is that, `Ad_system` can have multiple `Ad_Campaings`, `Ad_Campaing` can have multiple `Ad_Groups` and `Ad_Groups` can have multiple `Keywords`, and for every `Keyword` there is a `report`. Should It be like this ? Because It kind of make sense to me, but it doesn't look correct. Primary key can also be:

`ad.system.name` for first table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name` for second table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name ad.group.name` for third table

`ad.system.name ad.campaing.name ad.group.name keyword` for fourth table

They will always be unique, but then `Report` will always have all DB columns in It, so it`s kind of redundant.  Is this approach that I have in diagram below correct ? or better one is that I just described. If I am not mistaken both should satisfy 3rd NF.

Here is diagram of DB, I can't post images yet.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsw6a.png